# Negative of When

Tags: negation, logic, portmanteau-words

I'm designing some programming code, and the language is an important piece of making it easy for readers of the design to understand the context and intent of the code.

In particular, I'm looking for a negative complement to the word `when` in the context below.

#### When

Reading the code in the positive with "when", it would be interpreted along the lines of the following:

> "when" condition *-> wait until the condition becomes true/is satisfied then do something*

e.g.

> "when" true *-> do something*
>
> "when" false *-> wait*

The word "when" describes to the reader both the waiting and conditional triggering (once) of an action upon a condition being met.

#### When negative

The complement is a mystery word/portmanteau "X", ought to describe the same but with the conditional logically inverted:

> "X" true *-> wait*
>
> "X" false *-> do something*

#### Options

Here are some possible options for what X might be, for thought:

- `whenNot`
- `whenNoLonger`
- `untilNot`

#### Example

So for an example, suppose there's a condition "temperature", that's either hot or cold, and we want to trigger when it is not cold, here's my best thought on how they'd be roughly written/interpreted to/from English:

```
The temperature, "whenNot" cold, we do something
The temperature, "whenNoLonger" cold, we do something
The temperature, "untilNot" cold, we do something
```

The one that strikes me as the most appropriate innate description is `whenNoLonger`, but a simpler, shorter alternative would be ideal.

Do any good succinct alternatives come to mind?

**Edit** Adding on the helpful comments I've garnered some ideas.

One option may be **heretofore** or **hitherto**, adverbs meaning essentially "before this time; until now."  So "the temperature, before this time cold, we now do something".  It's old englishy but otherwise seems apt.

One might also use **thus far** but there's no guarantee that the condition of "not cold" is not immediately met (i.e. "thus far" presumes or might indicate a history of state, that may not actually be known)

Comment: `when` `sunny` -> `put on shades` vs  ***`until`*** `sunny` -> `open umbrella`. No?

Comment: I'm actually starting to believe this is an XY-problem. You are looking for a negation of "when", but you describe having implemented "when" to mean "until". Fixing that, you are looking at "Until" and a negative form, which could be "UntilNot".

Comment: @DanBron  The `when` and `until` would appear to be substitutable; it's the application of a negation to the condition upon which we are waiting.

Comment: But *when* doesn't mean *until*. Look at my example. *When* it rains, you open an umbrella. *Until* it rains, we will continue to enjoy our picnic in the park.  They have opposite time senses.

Comment: @oerkelens Yes I think that's a good way to look think about it.  Using `when` in this way is pretty common – here's an example of a popular library that uses `when` in exactly the way contemplated: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @DanBron Yes, I see.  I think the innate problem with `until` is that it overcomplicates the logical proposition; e.g. `when rain, open umbrella` would become `until rain wait, then open umbrella`.  We want the consequence to follow the condition; intermediary state is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm afraid this is becoming too much of a programming question, but that _when_ in jQuery_ is a delegate - nobody is _waiting_ for anything, it just gets executed when that query finishes. That is very different from "waiting until some condition is true or false".

Comment: I may be missing your point. I don't see a need for any additional syntax for *until* vs. *when*. The word *until* embeds the notion of a duration, of waiting. *When rain, open umbrella*, *Until rain, picnic*.

Comment: @DanBron The question is not so much "when rain / until rain", but `when rain` and `when rain stops`.

Comment: Then `after rain`?

Comment: @oerkelens That's an insightful point about the delegate vs condition.  The condition in the jQuery library is that the query completes i.e. `$.when query` is the same as `$.when query-is-complete` (if the query does not complete the `.then` is not called but rather `.catch`).

Comment: I think perhaps there's some loose thinking in the "scenario" as presented here. As @oerkelens points out, in most modern programming contexts, ***if*** some code doesn't execute ***unless*** some condition is true, there isn't really a concept of ***waiting*** for that condition to become true. It's normally just a matter of some function being called - if the condition is true it does something, otherwise it doesn't (since it gets called repeatedly, sooner or later the condition probably will be true, but the code itself isn't "waiting"). I'd say the "antonym" of **IF** (=WHEN) is **ELSE**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Promises/futures are present in virtually every modern language and are, by definition, waiting upon fulfillment of a condition.  They are often even called `when`, as in e.g. Angular/$q.when, jQuery/$.when, Q.js/q.when, when.js.  (As a matter of interest, I'm writing `.when` and its complement, however so named, for Knockout.js observables.)

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt: All that occurs to me on the "semantic" front is that ***when** [condition]* more strongly implies the condition *will be true sometimes*, where ***if*** is more neutral as to that possibility. But people often try to exploit that subtle distinction, so every now and then you have to put them straight by saying [*You mean 'if, not 'when'*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22when+not+if+said%22#tbm=bks&q=%22if+not+when+said%22&*). Interestingly, we apparently say *You mean 'when', not 'if'* far more often, whatever *that* implies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Lol.

Comment: There is the old term **lest** for 'Uh-oh should something happen.'

Answer (score 6):

A common word for *when not* is *unless*.

> **unless** *conjunction*
>   Except if (used to introduce the case in which a statement being made is not true or valid)
>   ‘unless you have a photographic memory, repetition is vital’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unless)

The phrase "*when X (is true), do Y*" says to do Y when X holds. For example, "when it rains, use an umbrella" says to use an umbrella when it rains.

The phrase "*unless X (is true), do Y*" says to do Y when X doesn't hold. The parallel example, "unless it rains, use an umbrella" says to use an umbrella when it's not raining.

Note that if you're looking for the rule to execute upon the *termination* of a condition, as opposed to just the negation of the condition, use [@Dan Bron's suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381267/negative-of-when#comment897815_381267): *after*.

Comment: I would never infer any waiting to happen is X is not true - intuitively, I would expect execution to continue, just not executing whatever jumbled form of "IF" you are trying to implement :)

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence.  The problem with `unless` is that it does not innately indicate that there's waiting.  I.e. `when` is not just describing the conditional (as in `if x/unless x`) but the delay `when = if not x then wait for x then do`.  Using `unless` would ordinarily indicate that the `do y` would never be called.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt *When* has the opposite property. Taking the umbrella example, the ordinary (English) sense has no 'wait' associated with the case that it's not raining. That is, if it's sunny and you require that *when it rains, use an umbrella*, the sense isn't *wait until it rains* - it's just *don't use an umbrella* (equivalent to your "never be called" behaviour). The use of *unless* is an exact complement. So if you add *waiting* to *when not*, it would be consistent to add *waiting* to *unless not*.

Comment: @oerkelens I think you're making the same objection as Brian in his (later) comment. Please see my reply to him.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt Instead of the bare *when* vs *unless*, you might want to consider *block when* vs *block unless*, where *block* has the standard programming meaning of suspending execution.

Comment: @Lawrence the noun (in my example `temperature`) is an asynchronous promises / future, so does not block.  Execution returns to the `when` upon the temperature changing, and continues from there to the next stage after the condition is met e.g. `temperature.when(cold).then(build_fire)`.  It's the `temperature.whenNoLonger(cold).then(douse_fire)` language that's the crux of this.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt As a production rule, read it as "fire when/unless (condition), and fire at most once for each time that (condition) changes". If the temperature is hot, *when(cold)* doesn't fire but *unless(cold)* does. If it's cold, *when(cold)* fires but *unless(cold)* doesn't. Isn't this what you're after?

Comment: @Lawrence It's not an immediate conditional; rather "when" describes waiting for a future state that may meet the conditional in the future.  It is, in effect, listening for the event of the state change, at which point it tests the condition, which - being met - causes the execution of the conclusion/next step.  So `unless cold` does not indicate that the condition will be tested in the future.

Comment: If you're looking for the rule to execute upon the *termination* of a condition, as opposed to the *presence* of the negation of the condition, I like Dan's suggestion of *after*.

Answer (score 3):

The commonly *used* alternative for this is *while*, with an empty body, meaning that while some condition is true, you just keep re-evaluation that condition. How you phrase the condition is entirely up to you - it's usually considered a good idea to *not* use negative condition- or boolean-names, so "ItsTooCold" would often be preferred to "ItsNotYetWarmeEnough". Think of negating that last one: if (NOT ItsNotYetWarmEnough).

```
while (ItIsTooCold); // <-- this line keeps repeating until "ItsTooCold" returns false.

//Do whatever you want to do when the temperature is high enough.
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's not phrasing the *conditional* (over which we have no control) but the *operation* of waiting until the conditional is (not) met.

Comment: There's definitely an ambiguity there, but in the context of the design it's clearly asynchronous, and so distinct from the immediate `if`/`if not` alternatives.  But I take your point.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby actually *has* exactly this:

- `if` -- run the following block once if condition is true.
- `while` -- run the following block while the condition remains true.
- `unless` -- run the following block once if condition is *false* (`if`'s complement).
- `until` -- run the following block while the condition remains *false* (`while`'s complement).

Honorable mention: Ruby also has `when`, but it's used more in a switch-case sort of statement (literally just case-when instead of switch-case).

---

I know this is on english SE and not programmingSE, but please consider whether you *should* add a feature like this, not just whether you *can*. It's not clearly a benefit in Ruby...while it does make nice things like this possible:

```
fail ArgumentError unless param > 0
```

it also allows antipatterns like this possible:

```
unless foo
    # something
else
    # something else
end
```

I think unless-else blocks are widely considered an antipattern. And in any case, for me personally, I almost always have to mentally convert an `unless` or an `until` back to a `if !` or `while !` -- it's just easier to reason about.

Comment: This would be exactly the thought provoking stuff that furthers the conversation 